# Настройка Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

После того как подкрутил гемфайл  (дописал `:x64_mingw`) ввел команду bundle update для последующего запуска rails server после чего мне выдало вот 
такую ошибку. http://joxi.ru/v29OG74IGyRZvr
Пробовал дальше ввести `gem install json -v '1.8.6'`, но ничего не получилось вот скрин - http://joxi.ru/VrwYzp3sKej8P2
Как я понял все упирается в установку этого гема, которую я не могу запустить. Кто-нибудь может мне подсказать как исправить ошибку или вообще запустить по другому rails server? Потому что изначально при запуске этой команды мне пишет:

> Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Сама ошибка:

```
d:/Tools/Ruby23/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:131:14: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
    In file included from d:/Tools/Ruby23/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                     from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                     from generator.c:1:
```

Comment: У вас систематически не устанавливается и не будет устанавливаться гем `json` (а также всё, что зависит от него и устанавливается после него), пока вы не почините то, что мешает его установке. На скриншотах ошибки я не наблюдаю, только предупреждения, ошибка либо выше, либо в логах. И не используйте в вопросах скриншоты без крайней необходимости, коей здесь нет. Советую также не заниматься разработкой под Ruby on Rails под Windows, т. к. сами видите, что ещё даже не начали, а проблемы уже возникают. Я обычно рекомендую виртуалку с Linux, с недавних пор можно использовать Linux-подсистему.

Comment: Если я скину то, что выше (скрин?), есть шанс, что прояснится вопрос?

Comment: Уже те скрины, что вы уже выложили, нужны исключительно чтобы показать текст на них. Прикладывайте лучше сам текст, а не картинку с ним.

Comment: generator.c: In function 'cState_space_before_set':
generator.c:1152:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1152:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast
ьake: *** [generator.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
Gem files will remain installed in D:/Tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspecti
on.
Results logged to D:/Tools/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
Возможность пролистывания вверх ограничена колесом прокрутки.

Comment: Не в комментарии, в вопрос. И нет, здесь нет описания возникшей ошибки, в приведенном вами сегменте сказано лишь, что она возникла. Ищите слово error выше или в указанных файлах журналов (логов).